# Save csv data to a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file with this data:

```
Sensor 1;;
9;5;9
6;4;7
4;2;1
Sensor 2;;
10;7;8
4;4;6
3;5;8
Sensor 3;;
5;4;6
5;1;2
9;7;1
```

I have tried many things but it does not work for me for all types of data. I make it read a line and save it in a list, and that consecutively, but it doesn't work for me. What the program should do is ask you which sensor you want and return the sensor name and show the path as an array within a dictionary. An example would be the following:

```
Sensor 1 : press 1
Sensor 2 : press 2
Sensor 3 : press 3

{Sensor 1: [[9,5,9],[6,4,7],[4,2,1]]}
```

The code has to be without imports

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file,  delimiter = ";")
    out_dict = {}
    current_key = ""
    for row in reader:
        if "Sensor" not in row[0]:
            if current_key:
                out_dict[current_key].append(row)
        else:
            current_key = row[0]
            out_dict[current_key] = []
            
print(out_dict)
```

or without csv

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    out_dict = {}
    current_key = ""
    for line in file.readlines():
        row = line.strip().split(';')
        if "Sensor" not in line:
            if current_key:
                out_dict[current_key].append(row)
        else:
            current_key = row[0]
            out_dict[current_key] = []
            
print(out_dict)
```

Comment: Would there be any way to do it without imports?

Comment: I mean, yes, I can change it, but whats the problem, ```csv``` is a standard package that comes with the python installation

Comment: I added without ```csv``` import, but I recommend using it for handling any csv files. The second code will break if for instance of one of the values in your csv file contained a```;``` character

Comment: Waht is current_key? it says me it's not defined

Comment: Does your file have the word ```Source``` in the first line? I edited the code to track only once the first line with the word Source is found.

Comment: All Python programmers need to be familiar with the standard library. It is a basic necessity. Otherwise you may waste time writing your own solution to a problem that has been very competently solved already. For example, reading a `.csv` file can involve tricky corner cases, such as with embedded commas and quotes. You are much better off taking the trouble to find out how *batteries included* can help you produce better code with less coding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, with no imports:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    t=f.readlines()

res={}

temp=''
for i in range(len(t)):
    if t[i][:6]=='Sensor':
        temp=t[i].strip().replace(';;', '')
        res[temp]=[]
    else:
        res[temp].append(t[i].strip().split(';'))

print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'Sensor 1': [['9', '5', '9'], ['6', '4', '7'], ['4', '2', '1']], 'Sensor 2': [['10', '7', '8'], ['4', '4', '6'], ['3', '5', '8']], 'Sensor 3': [['5', '4', '6'], ['5', '1', '2'], ['9', '7', '1']]}
```